# Checking multiple cell locations using target.address with embedded if statements

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to display two types of images, one I will call the class (cylindrical or spherical) and the other is the subclass (split, multi-frag, and end cap). In my spreadsheet users have two drop-down lists where they can select from the different classes and subclasses. So I have an image for each classes and six for the subclasses (three for each class). I am using embedded if statements to first check for the class and display the corresponding class image and then within that class's if statement I am further checking for the subclass and trying to display that image accordingly but it is not working. It is only displaying the class image and does not do anything for the subclass images. I'm doing this within the worksheet event handler. I am by no means an expert and am looking for help from those in this form that know way more than I do when it comes to this. Thank you

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)
'change cylindrical/spherical vessel image based on user selection
If Target.Address = "$D$9" Then
    If range(Target.Address) = "Cylindrical" Then
        PVType.Visible = True
        PVSPH.Visible = False
        'change vessel FRAGMENTATION image based on user selection
        If Target.Address = "$D$36" Then
            If range(Target.Address) = "Center Split" Then
                CYL_SPLIT.Visible = True
                CYL_EC.Visible = False
                CYL_MF.Visible = False
                SPH_SPLIT.Visible = False
                SPH_EC.Visible = False
                SPH_MF.Visible = False
            ElseIf range(Target.Address) = "End cap" Then
                    CYL_SPLIT.Visible = False
                    CYL_EC.Visible = True
                    CYL_MF.Visible = False
                    SPH_SPLIT.Visible = False
                    SPH_EC.Visible = False
                    SPH_MF.Visible = False
                    ElseIf range(Target.Address) = "Multi-frag" Then
                        CYL_SPLIT.Visible = False
                        CYL_EC.Visible = False
                        CYL_MF.Visible = True
                        SPH_SPLIT.Visible = False
                        SPH_EC.Visible = False
                        SPH_MF.Visible = False
                        Else
                            CYL_SPLIT.Visible = False
                            CYL_EC.Visible = False
                            CYL_MF.Visible = False
                            SPH_SPLIT.Visible = False
                            SPH_EC.Visible = False
                            SPH_MF.Visible = False
            End If
        End If 'End CYL frag image
        
        ElseIf range(Target.Address) = "Spherical" Then
            PVType.Visible = False
            PVSPH.Visible = True
        'change vessel FRAGMENTATION image based on user selection
            If Target.Address = "$D$36" Then
                If range(Target.Address) = "Center Split" Then
                    CYL_SPLIT.Visible = False
                    CYL_EC.Visible = False
                    CYL_MF.Visible = False
                    SPH_SPLIT.Visible = True
                    SPH_EC.Visible = False
                    SPH_MF.Visible = False
                ElseIf range(Target.Address) = "End cap" Then
                        CYL_SPLIT.Visible = False
                        CYL_EC.Visible = False
                        CYL_MF.Visible = False
                        SPH_SPLIT.Visible = False
                        SPH_EC.Visible = True
                        SPH_MF.Visible = False
                        ElseIf range(Target.Address) = "Multi-frag" Then
                            CYL_SPLIT.Visible = False
                            CYL_EC.Visible = False
                            CYL_MF.Visible = False
                            SPH_SPLIT.Visible = False
                            SPH_EC.Visible = False
                            SPH_MF.Visible = True
                            Else
                                CYL_SPLIT.Visible = False
                                CYL_EC.Visible = False
                                CYL_MF.Visible = False
                                SPH_SPLIT.Visible = False
                                SPH_EC.Visible = False
                                SPH_MF.Visible = False
                End If
            End If 'End SPH frag image
        
        End If
        
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More concise:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim vType, vSubtype

    'change cylindrical/spherical vessel image based on user selection
    If Target.Address = "$D$9" Or Target.Address = "$D$36" Then
        
        vType = Me.Range("D9").Value
        vSubtype = Me.Range("D36").Value
        
        PVtype.Visible = (vType = "Cylindrical")
        PVSPH.Visible = (vType = "Spherical")
        
        If vType = "Cylindrical" Then
            CYL_SPLIT.Visible = (vSubtype = "Center Split")
            CYL_EC.Visible = (vSubtype = "End Cap")
            CYL_MF.Visible = (vSubtype = "Multi-frag")
            SPH_SPLIT.Visible = False
            SPH_EC.Visible = False
            SPH_MF.Visible = False
        ElseIf vType = "Spherical" Then
            CYL_SPLIT.Visible = False
            CYL_EC.Visible = False
            CYL_MF.Visible = False
            SPH_SPLIT.Visible = (vSubtype = "Center Split")
            SPH_EC.Visible = (vSubtype = "End Cap")
            SPH_MF.Visible = (vSubtype = "Multi-frag")
        Else
            'set all to not visible
        End If
    End If
   
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks Tim! That solved my issue and you approach/method is going to make things a lot easier for me when I deal with these types of situations from now on!